# How can I set a title/caption for an overlay item and create onclick/long pressed listener for that item to start an new activity?

Tags: android, overlayitem, android-mapview

My application will find the users around myself and shown it on the map.
I can add the overlayItem on the mapView but how can I add some caption for the image for example the user name.
[image]

After I clicked the item, a dialog box is shown.

[image]

Can I set a listener that can invoke a new activity when the user clicked the box?
My intention is somehow I can go to the user profile by the overlayItem.
Is it possible to do so?
Thanks

**i have found the solution and wanted to share for ppl who is interested.
As i cannot answer to my own question, i will edit the question.**

For added caption for the overlayItem:

```
 @Override
public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
{
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

    if (shadow == false)
    {
        //cycle through all overlays
        for (int index = 0; index < mOverlays.size(); index++)
        {
            OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);

            // Converts lat/lng-Point to coordinates on the screen
            GeoPoint point = item.getPoint();
            Point ptScreenCoord = new Point() ;
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, ptScreenCoord);

            //Paint
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            paint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
            paint.setARGB(150, 0, 0, 0); // alpha, r, g, b (Black, semi see-through)

            //show text to the right of the icon
            canvas.drawText(item.getTitle(), ptScreenCoord.x, ptScreenCoord.y+mTextSize, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

For starting a new activity in the dialog box you need to override the onTap method in the ItemizedOverlay class:

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to see this user's profile?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   Intent i = new Intent();
                    i = new Intent(mContext,
                            ViewFdProfile.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(i);
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();


    return true;
}
```

Hope this help, cheers!

Comment: Actually on SO you can answer your own question - and mark it as correct.